# Amazon SNS end point arn

Tags: amazon-sns

Is there a way to get the end point arn from message id which is sent as a response by aws's sns? We didn't store the full response , but only the message id. We have sent push's to individual users not to topics.

Comment: No, there is not; at least not through a public API - it might be accessible through Amazon's internal logs, but that's it.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this though? Perhaps there's an underlying problem that can be solved differently here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a reverse lookup of message id to recipients ARNs.  Amazon doesn't store anything like that for you - that amount of data would get out of control across the millions of pushes that are sent every day by SNS.

You would have to store this association yourself in your own data store going forward.